# Null pointer exception during deployment

Tags: java, jar, weblogic-10.x, ojdbc

I am trying to deploy my application on web logic and it seems that i am getting Null Pointer Exception.

The exception is because the server is not picking up ojdbc.jar in my lib. Now, i added the same in class path but still its not picking up the jar. 
I have made my war using Netbeans.

There is no compilation error. The error comes during run time.

Weblogic version -- 10.3

JDK -- 1.7

Netbeans -- 8.1 pointed to jdk 1.7

Can anyone provide their input ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should post exception log here. Also, make sure that you follow the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jdbc_admin/third_party_drivers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really think weblogic is not picking up your classpath jars then create a new file weblogic.xml with following content inside WEB-INF directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Hi The issue was of context lookup. The jar was getting added but the weblogic was not able to lookup the resource as it was not present in JNDI.